# Is it possible to use 'TEXT-XXX' when declaring variable?

Tags: abap

I'm doing self-learning in ABAP given by my company and I'm out of resources.

> The output should be:  "Employee Number"
>
> "First Name"
>
> "Last Name"
>
> "Birthdate"
>
> "Dream Salary"
>
> "Hobby"

The instruction is: Display the following using variables with correct data types.
Text symbols should be assigned to the values listed below.

text-001 Employee Number

text-002 First Name

text-003 Last Name

text-004 Birthdate

text-005 Dream Salary

text-006 Hobby

However, We are not allowed to use the dash(-) when declaring variables in ABAP.

Is there any workaround for that?

Here's my code

```
DATA: text_001 TYPE String,
      text_002 TYPE String,
      text_003 TYPE String,
      text_004 TYPE String,
      text_005 TYPE String,
      text_006 TYPE String,

MOVE 'EMPLOYEE NUMBER' TO text_001.
MOVE 'EMPLOYEE NUMBER' TO text_002.
MOVE 'EMPLOYEE NUMBER' TO text_003.
MOVE 'EMPLOYEE NUMBER' TO text_004.
MOVE 'EMPLOYEE NUMBER' TO text_005.
MOVE 'EMPLOYEE NUMBER' TO text_006.

WRITE: text_001,
     / text_002,
     / text_003,
     / text_004,
     / text_005,
     / text_006.
```

While it outputs the needed output, the application that checks my code doesn't accept the code as the correct answer. Since I need to use the:

**text-001** instead of text_001

Comment: Please indicate the exact message shown by the application.

Comment: @SandraRossi It is an internal program made by my employer which says "Not matched on the correct program" I wish it has hints so I can check which I went wrong tbh.

Comment: We can't say anything on internal custom programs if they are not described in details. Anyway, I guess it mimics standard checks which advise to define translatable text literals (when these literals can be possibly translated, otherwise mark them using the Pragma `##NOTEXT`), for instance by using Text Symbols. Search ABAP documentation for more information.

Comment: FWIW the dash (-) is used for component access in ABAP, e.g. `user-name` accesses the _name_ component of the _user_ structure. In the same way, text-001 accesses the 001 component of the text structure (which is predefined through the Text Elements)

Comment: This basic ABAP syntax should've been part of your course _before_ giving you such an exercise though ...

Answer (score 5):

I think you might have misunderstood the instructions. I believe that you are supposed to use text symbols for constant strings and variables for variable strings.

[Text symbols](https://help.sap.com/viewer/10a002cd6c531014b5e1cb16d2455072/7.0.37/en-US/1e401ad6ee3c11d1951d0000e8353423.html) are a technique to store static text strings which appear in your program separately from your ABAP code. The main reason for doing that is i18n. Those texts can later be translated by someone who does not know how to program ABAP. When the end-user then uses a different logon language than you did when you created the program, then the program will automatically use the translated texts.

You can create text symbols in SE80 by going to *"Goto"*->*"Text Elements"* in the menu bar and then select the tab "Text Symbols".

You can create text symbols in Eclipse by right-clicking into the sourcecode and selecting *"Open Others"*->*"Text Elements"* in the context menu.

Each text symbol has a 3-digit number. You can then refer to the number like this:

```
WRITE: / text-001, gv_firstname.
```

Comment: It would be better to not use the format TEXT-###, but rather use 'textliteral'(###). As the help text linked explains, with the latter construct you will still get some meaningful text if the text element is not maintained in the logon language. And it makes the code easier to read.